# Laplacian of Scalar Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, scalar-fields

My question entails the laplacian of a scalar function and **I would like to express it in polar coordinates**.

Stuck on whether I am supposed to use one of the forms of Laplace's equation to help me solve or do something else.

Any advice/guidance/help would be warmly appreciated.

-nomad609

Answer (score 0):

Well there are harder stuff than this.

Anyway, you have $\nabla^2 f = \nabla \cdot \nabla f = 1/r\partial_r (r\partial_r f)+1/r \partial_\theta (1/r \partial_\theta f)$.

Straightforward, plug the second identity to the first.

Comment: Also I am unsure what you mean by plugging the second identity to the first. Could you please elaborate? Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: @nomad609 just write down $\nabla f = F(r,\theta)\hat{r}+G(r,\theta)\hat{\theta}$. so in your formula for $\nabla \cdot (\nabla f) = 1/r \partial_r(rF(r,\theta))+1/r \partial_\theta G(r,\theta)$; find $F,G$ by using your second identity for grad; there's nothing to it.