# Finding the Laplace of a function in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform, laplace-method

Please see the attached image, containing my question and my solution.

> **Question:** Show *[using the formulas for gradient and divergence in terms of polar coordinates]* that the Lapalacian of a scalar function $f(r,\theta)$ is given by
>   $$
> \nabla \cdot \nabla f = \partial_r^2 f + \frac 1r \partial_r f + \frac 1{r^2} \partial_{\theta}^2 f
> $$

Attached image: [http://imgur.com/a/XUZ1M](https://imgur.com/a/XUZ1M)

I gather that the RHS is obtained by substituting the 1st result into the 2nd which then gives the answer after doing the two differentiations.

I have ajusted the notation and I have solved via a longer way, it is only that I have not looked at this area in a long time, any advice on where to start - as in like what does the initial substitution look like.

Thanks

-nomad609

Note- this question is much different to any other previous threads, I have uploaded the information to elucidate this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function question 12](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981901/function-question-12)

Comment: Well no- one is respondding and I have added additional information.

Comment: You have had thorough comments to your previous post that were equivalent to answers.

Comment: said response didn't entirely help me I feel, I have uploaded completes solutions via other ways. I just feel that regarding this particular question, I am still stuck after all this time. And I am kindly requesting assistance. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the gradient first

\begin{equation}
F = \nabla f = \hat{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \hat{\theta}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = \hat{r}F_r + \hat{\theta} F_\theta,
\end{equation}

with $F_r = \partial f/\partial r$ and $F_\theta = r^{-1}\partial f/\partial \theta$. Now calculate the divergence of the field $F$

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \nabla f = \nabla \cdot F = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(r Fr) + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} F_\theta = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \right) 
\end{equation}

which can be rearranged as

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot\nabla f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you sir, I now see how it is done.